# How to create an Azure DevOps chart with more than 1 group by criteria?

Tags: azure-devops

I know how to create an Azure DevOps chart with a group by criteria.
But is it possible to group by more than 1 criteria?

For instance I d love to group by task status and "assigned to" fields.

I suppose it is not supported but I'd love to be proved wrong. :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not support to group by more than 1 criteria.
Currently, only one filed is supported.
[image]

Comment: OK thx for the answer. Quite a pity though.